# 'Sparsely' vs 'Thinly'

Tags: differences, adverbs

What is the difference between *sparsely* and *thinly*?
Can these words be interchangeable?
May I use *thinly furnished* or *thinly populated* as well as *sparsely furnished* and *thinly populated*.

Comment: yep you can do that

Comment: Thinly & sparsely are synonymous.

Comment: @mahmudkoya I don't think they are. I would use 'sparsely' when talking about something made up of discrete units which have space around them, so it works for furniture as it might work for say... flowers in a lawn 'the grass was sparsely dotted with daisies'. Thinly I would use for substances which are spread in a continuous layer which does not have much depth, 'thinly spread butter' for example. There is some overlap eg you can find reference to seeds being sown either thinly or sparsely.

Comment: sparsely :In a thinly dispersed manner; in small numbers.(https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sparsely)

Comment: Mostly synonymous. But I can think of cases where I would opt for one over the other. Although I don't really agree with @Spagirl, I think *thinly* does carry a connotation of an even distribution, whereas *sparsely* can more easily encompass clumpy or random distributions.

Comment: @Spagirl perhaps coarseness or granularity plays a role. I would say *the grass seed was spread thinly*, but *seedlings began to appeared sparsely* after the fire.* In that sense, I do agree with your comments.

Comment: @mahmudkoya I should've qualified my comment as 'I don't think they **always** are', which I did initially but that post failed to send and I forgot to be as careful on my second attempt. Apologies for that. As I say, I certainly agree there is overlap. I don't think the ODO link supports an absolute sparsely=thinly, so much that 'thinly' can be used  *in association with other words* to describe what 'sparsely' does in one. To be fair, They do give 'Sparsely' as a definition of thinly, but not until you get down to the third definition. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/thinly

Comment: I of a mind of Phil Sweet about the differences in the words, especially in terms of distribution.  To add a bit I would equate Sparse with Rare, and Thin with Stretched.  Of course there might be situations where they work equally well, but others when one is better than another.

Comment: The usages are slightly different sometimes.  Read some usage notes in some dictionaries.